# How to get `data-properties` of element in Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Now, I have retrieved the element data. But, I don't know how to get data of `data-properties`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9Oxg.png)

I tried:
`$('#checkout_shipping_address_id').on('select2:select', function (e) {`
`var data = e.params.data;`
`console.log(data.element.getAttribute[data-properties]);`
`});`
`but It's not working`

Comment: HI, can you show your html and the way you generate these options ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to change event handler to `change` instead of `select`
2. If you need to get the attributes you can do it with `attr` method.

```
    $('#checkout_shipping_address_id').on('change', function (e) {
        var data = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-properties')
        console.log(data); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with selected handler.

```
$('#checkout_shipping_address_id').on('change', function (e) {
        var data = $('#checkout_shipping_address_id option:selected').attr('data-properties')
        console.log(data); 
    });
```